# Update Another Model's Attribute Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have two models, call them `Animal` and `AnimalComment`.  They look like this:

```
class AnimalComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment, :num
end

class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_ accessible :species, :comment
end
```

I when ever I create a comment in `Animal` I would like it to add that comment into the `:comment` field of my `AnimalComment` Model.

My vision of how this works is I type in a comment in my `animals/new` webpage, and when I click `Submit`  The comment get's added as a field inside my `AnimalComment` webpage and is displayed there.

Hope this makes sense.  Any ideas?

Comment: can animal have multiple comment?

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you need help with anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure it makes sense to have the same data stored in two places.  Perhaps the models should be related (i.e. an `Animal` `has_many` `Comments`).

In any case, your requirement can be satisfied with a callback.

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :species, :comment
  after_save :create_animal_comment

  def create_animal_comment
    AnimalComment.create(comment: self.comment)
  end
end
```

The `after_save` method tells Rails to run the `Animal#create_animal_comment` method every time an `Animal` record is created.  `self.comment` refers to the comment in the `Animal` model.

Comment: Syntax error:  `attar_accessible` should be `attr_accessible`

Answer (score 1):

First, create associations. Then save the comment only in the AnimalComment table. Use `delegate` in the Animal model to access it, or get it through the association.